# Zoom RelativeLayout with the background image bitmap in Android

Tags: android, zooming, android-relativelayout

How to zoom in - out relative layout containing child views with the background image?

I am able to zoom in out relative layout but the background image bitmap on the relative layout is constant and not able to scale.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you? It's library for zooming in/out an image view.
https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView